# How to cross update of view between nattable and Jface view

Tags: view, eclipse-rcp, jface, rcp, nattable

Eclipse RCP View Communication ,where one view contains nattable and another views contains jface controls like button, dropdown.

Currently for example there is 3 view/Editor as shown below [image: example image]

View1 - contains employee details which is a Nattable and 
        it's cell contains data like String, Long, boolean, date value.
        each row represent one data,and other views are corresponding data of 
        selected row

View2 -  shows Address which is corresponding to the selected row in the View 1,
         User can modify data of view2.

View3 - shows department details of employe, which can also be modified

So all 3 views present data of one model say Employee

```
   Employee 
     |_Name 
     |_EmpId
     |_Married
     |_DOJ
     |_Address
         |_Type
         |_City Name
         |_State
         |_PinCode
     |_Department Details
         |_Department
         |_Project
         |_Manager
```

Problem:

I want to know what is best way of  communcation between views1  and other view such that

1. On selection of row in view1 then other two view should be update correspondingly;
2. If any data changes in view2/view3 then view 1 should get notification for data change in other view
3. when condition 2 occurs then I want to show dirty row in view1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical approach for inter view communication in an E4 application related to your described scenario is to use the `ESelectionService` to trigger handling of a selection for opening another view, and to communicate back via the Eclipse 4 event system.

For scenario one to open a view based on the selection in a NatTable you could use the `E4SelectionListener` in the *NatTable Eclipse 4 Extension Feature*. It is a `ILayerListener` that forwards the selection to the `ESelectionService`. An example can be found in the [NatTable examples](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples.e4/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/e4/part/SelectionListenerExample.java).

To inform view 1 about changes in another view, I would suggest to use the `IEventBroker` to send an event from view2/view3 and react on the event in view1. This way the views are decoupled as much as possible. [Eclipse 4 event system](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4EventSystem/article.html) is a good starting point for learning about the event system.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dirt Fauth for the response,  I also would like to ask one more thing that currently application is based on 3.x  and not based on e4 , 
so is it possible to achieve the same in 3.x  ? and if yes then how ?
        I though it can be achieve as follows but not looks like a good solution :
  A. view1 to other view -> via selection service of 3.x 
  B. view 2 and view 3 -> also can be done via selection service but each view has many control/widgets,in this case I have to register each control as selection provider from all view.
Kindly suggest me the best to do so in 3.x.

Comment: For 3.x you can use the `RowSelectionProvider` which is shown in this example: https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_500_Layers/_505_Selection/_5054_SelectionProviderExample.java The communcation back from a subview to the main view to make only the main view dirty after a detail change, actually I am not sure how this was done the E3 way. Quite some years have passed. If you use a newer platform and just the E3 API, the event stuff should work the same way.